# Слова-предложения.

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите,пожалуйста,какие существуют слова-предложения.
Относятся ли они к какой-нибудь части речи?
Всегда ли выделяются знаками препинания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Среди простых предложений выделяется группа предложений, выраженных одним словом или неразложимым сочетанием частиц. Такие предложения обозначают простое утверждение или отрицание, выражают согласие или несогласие, дают эмоциональную оценку предшествующему высказыванию или содержат побуждение к действию.  Слова-предложения представляют собой ***особый структурный тип*** и не могут быть отнесены ни к двусоставным предложениям, ни к односоставным. Они не имеют отдельных членов предложения и не выполняют номинативной функции, так как ничего не называют.
Слова-предложения употребляются в диалогической речи. Они свойственны только разговорному языку.

Типы слов-предложений
Слова-предложения делятся на несколько групп в зависимости от их функции в речи.
*Утвердительные слова-предложения*:
- Серой пахнет. Это так нужно?
- Да (Ч.).
- Становитесь по местам. Пора. Луна восходит?
- **Точно так** (Ч.).
- **Правда, правда..**. - подумал Посудин. - И как я этого раньше не знал! (Ч.).
- Нy, **хорошо, хорошо**, - продолжал он, не глядя на мужиков, - я прикажу - хорошо, ступайте. (Мужики не поднимались.) - Ну, да ведь сказал вам... **хорошо**. Ступайте же (Т.).
- А преконфузно, однако же, должно быть, если откажут.
- **Еще бы!** (Г.).
- Прощай, Сергей... Случится тебе быть на Волге - может, заглянешь?.. Симбирского уезда деревня Мазло, Николо-Лыковской волости...
- **Ладно**, - сказал Сережка (М. Г.).
- Вам бы надо побриться, Глеб Иванович.
- **Конечно**, я сейчас (Закр.).
*Отрицательные слова-предложения*:
- О, **нет, нет**! (Ч.).
- **Нет**, - ответил гость (Ч.).
- **Неправда**, любите (Б. Пол.).
Слово-предложение может представлять собой ответ, неопределенный по содержанию, значение его - промежуточное между утверждением и отрицанием:
- Вот увидишь, Савватеич, после тебе стыдно будет.
- **Ничего**, Федор Григорьевич, голый разбоя не боится (Б. Пол.).
*Вопросительные слова-предложения*:
- Петруша!
- **А**? (Ч.).
- Евгений Николаевич!
- **Ну**? - Листницкий свесил ноги (Шол.).
- Ну-с, Тетушка, - сказал хозяин, - сначала мы с вами споем, а потом попляшем. **Хорошо**? (Ч.).
- **Неужто**? (Ч.).
- **Да**? (Ч.).
*Междометные эмоционально-оценочные* предложения (выраженные эмоциональными междометиями):
Я ответил, что она [Маша] осталась в крепости на руках у попадьи. - **Ай, ай, ай**! - заметил генерал (П.).
- **Батюшки**! - изумился тонкий, - Миша! Друг детства! Откуда ты взялся? (Ч.).
- Боже мой, окунь! **Ах, ах...** Скорей! Сорвался! (Ч.).
- **Тьфу**! - удивилась Раиса, пожимая плечами и крестясь (Ч.).
- **Увы**, Лазо Ильич (Б. Пол.).
*Междометные побудительные предложения* (выраженные императивными междометиями):
- Бедная, плачет теперь где-нибудь в потемках, - думал он. - А извозчик на нее: **цыц! цыц!** (Ч.).
...Незнакомец вдруг схватил себя за голову, изобразил на своем лице ужас и закричал: - **Караул!** (Ч.).
- **Ау!** Константин Гаврилович!.. **Ау!** (Ч.).
- Не играйте! - замахали старшины музыкантам. - **Тс!**.. Егор Нилыч спит... (Ч.).
- **И баста!** - вслух сказал Олесь, останавливая тягостные мысли (Б. Пол.).***(Валгина Н.С.,Розенталь Д.Э., Фомина М.И. Современный русский язык)***

Слова предложения - это преимущественно частицы и междометия. Членами предложения они не являются. Наиболее часто употребляются слова-предложения  "да", "нет". Так как это всё-таки предложение, знаки при нём необходимы. Чаще это знак завершения.